# What is the differrence between `* text=auto` and `* text eol=lf` in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

I am looking again and again at the documentation of [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) but I cannot find a clear answer on what is the differrence between these two:

`* text=auto`

`* text eol=lf`

Also is `text=auto` intended only for use with `*` or it can also be used with specific extensions? In such a case what is the differrence?

`*.txt text=auto`

`*.txt text eol=lf`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Before Git 2.36.0, the `eol=lf` setting overrides any `text` setting, and since you have chosen to apply this to every path, only the `eol=lf` setting will matter, if you use that.
After Git 2.36.0, the `eol=lf` only applies if `text` is set, unspecified, or set to `auto` and Git determines it is a text file.

#### Full explanation

Let's start with this and work outwards:

> Also is `text=auto` intended only for use with `*` or it can also be used with specific extensions?

Patterns may include extensions. The `text=auto` part is an *attribute setting*, and the patterns select which attributes to apply to which file(s).

#### How Git Reads a `.gitattributes` File

Each line in `gitattributes` matches, or does not match, some path name such as `dir1/dir2/file.ext` or `README.md` or whatever. As the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) says:

> Each line in `gitattributes` file is of form:
>
> ```
> pattern attr1 attr2 ...
> ```
>
> That is, a pattern followed by an attributes list, separated by whitespaces. Leading and trailing whitespaces are ignored. Lines that begin with # are ignored. Patterns that begin with a double quote are quoted in C style. When the pattern matches the path in question, the attributes listed on the line are given to the path.

Hence, `*` is the *pattern*. These "patterns" are the same as those in [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) files, except that negative patterns are disallowed. Thus, you can use patterns like `*.txt` and `*.jpg` to match file name extensions, or patterns like `dir1/*` to match files within a specific directory. Both `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files can be local to a specific directory as well, in which case they apply to files in that directory and its subdirectories, but not to paths higher in the tree.

Now, for `text` vs `text=auto`, and for `eol=lf` or not, we find the following:

> Each attribute can be in one of these states for a given path:
>
> **Set**
> The path has the attribute with special value "true"; this is
> specified by listing only the name of the attribute in the
> attribute list.
>
> **Unset** [details snipped, but see below]
>
> **Set to a value**
> The path has the attribute with specified string value; this is
> specified by listing the name of the attribute followed by an equal
> sign = and its value in the attribute list.
>
> **Unspecified**
> No pattern matches the path, and nothing says if the path has or does not have the attribute, the attribute for the path is said to be Unspecified.

(The wording on the last one is particularly poor, in my opinion. It really means "of all patterns matching the path," none said anything about this attribute.")

So for `text`, the attribute is *set*, and for `text=auto`, the attribute is *set to a value*. The *value* part in this case is `auto`. Since the pattern is `*`, it applies to all files.

This same logic applies to the `eol=lf` item. If, firstly, this `eol=lf` occurs in some pattern, and secondly, that pattern matches the file in question, then the `eol` attribute is set to a value, and the value is `lf`. Since your suggested line was `* text eol=lf`, this would make `eol` *set to a value*, and would make `text` *set*, but *not set to a value*.

If you write, in a single `.gitattributes` file, the *two line sequence*:

```
* text=auto
* text eol=lf
```

The second line's `text` overrides the first one's, so that `text` is *set* (but not to a value) and `eol` is *set to a value*, with the value being `lf`. Both lines matched, and the second line overrode the first.

If you *reverse* the two lines:

```
* text eol=lf
* text=auto
```

Then again *both lines match* but now the second line only overrides the `text` setting, so now you have `text` *set to* `auto` and `eol` *set to* `lf`.

#### How the `text` Attribute Applies to Files

The very next section of the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) says:

> This attribute [`text`] enables and controls end-of-line normalization... [If it is]
>
> **Set**
> ... enables end-of-line normalization and marks the path as a text file ...
>
> **Unset**
> ... tells Git not to attempt any end-of-line conversion upon checkin or checkout ...
>
> **Set to string value "auto"**
> ... If Git decides that the content is text ...
>
> **Unspecified**
> ... Git uses the `core.autocrlf` configuration variable ...

(which means you have to go chase down the [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to find out what `core.autocrlf` does if you leave `text` unspecified).

You have chosen to either set it for every file or set it to `auto` for every file. The former means "do conversion for every file" and the latter (the `auto` setting) means: *Hey, Git, please decide for me whether the file is text or not. If you decide that it is text, do the conversion.*

#### How `eol=lf` Applies to Files

Just below the description for the `text` setting is this description for the `eol` setting. Before Git 2.36.0, it read:

> This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the
> working directory. It enables end-of-line conversion without any
> content checks, effectively setting the `text` attribute.
>
> **Set to string value "crlf"**
> ... [snipped because you set `lf`]
>
> **Set to string value "lf"**
> This setting forces Git to normalize line endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF when the file is checked out.

So, if you have `eol=lf` set for a path (and with `*` as the pattern, it will be set for *every* path), Git will treat every file as text and do conversion from CRLF line-endings to LF line-endings on "checkin" (this is poorly phrased, again: the conversion actually occurs during the `git add` step). Git will do nothing during checkout (this too, is not perfectly phrased: the conversion, or in this case non-conversion, happens during extraction from index to work-tree).

After Git 2.36.0, the description now reads:

> This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the working directory. This attribute has effect only if the text attribute is set or unspecified, or if it is set to auto, the file is detected as text, and it is stored with LF endings in the index.
> [rest of the description omitted for brevity]

This means that `text` is now taken into account for `eol`. In your case, you either set `text` or set it to `auto`. In the first case the `eol` attribute always applies for matching patterns. In the second case it only applies if git determines that the file is a text file.

#### If You Use Different Patterns, You Get Different Results

Note that if you choose a pattern like `*.txt`, then these attributes are *set* only for paths that match the pattern. For other paths, these attributes remain *unset*. You should, therefore, look back at [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and see what happens when these attributes are *unset*.

You can, of course, do this:

```
* -text
*.txt eol=lf
```

The first line will explicitly *unset* `text` on all files, leaving `eol` unspecified on all files. The second line then *sets to a value* `eol=lf` for `*.txt` files, overriding the unspecified value. Now Git will apply the `eol=lf` rules to all files whose name matches `*.txt`, and use the unspecified (`eol` and *unset*) text rules for all remaining files.

This special `-text` syntax is the stuff I snipped above. Using `text=false` **does not** *unset* `text`, but rather leaves `text` set to the string value `false`. This has the same effect as leaving `text` unspecified (not specifically *unset*). Using `-text` gives it the special *unset* setting.

The difference between an *unset* `text` and an *unspecified* `text` is that when `text` is unspecified, Git could attempt to *guess* (based on the `core.*` settings like `core.autocrlf`) whether to do conversions. However, when `text` is specifically *unset*, Git will not do any guessing or conversion at all for that file.

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation. Can I conclude from the above that on this page: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ the "`text eol=lf`: Git will always convert line endings to LF on checkout", is wrong? Should it be, "git will not perform any conversion on checkout", or do they actually have the exact same meaning?

Comment: Yes: with `eol=lf` the setting for `text` is irrelevant, and Git will apply the CRLF-to-LF rule on "input" conversion (roughly, at `git add` time), and no end-of-line changes on "output" conversion (roughly, at `git checkout`). Note that once there has been any input-side conversion (add and commit), the sacrosanct committed version has LF-only endings, so that "no conversion" and "conversion to LF-only" would have the same *effect*. This makes it hard to detect that there is no conversion occurring—but [the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/convert.c) says "no conversion" here.

Comment: This explanation is very complete and helpful. I think you meant 'the _two line sequence: \n `* text=auto` \n `* text eol=lf`' instead of that last `text eol` being set to `elf` (unless I'm missing some assembler programming going on here.)

Comment: @bballdave025: oops, yes, that was supposed to be `eol=lf`, Typos! Will fix.

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong. "eol" is used for checkout/output (working dir), not checkin/input. See this recent documentation: https://github.com/bk2204/git/commit/a63d17f20642a7a27beaf9c044eb6fd8ac7a3000#diff-8c2ad6307733b92b3f5a6a70a3f3bbe1076c0fdf4da66c3633f90d15c6cf118a.

Comment: @BrunoGomes: It's very messy, and version-dependent as a bug was fixed in Git 2.10 (Sep 2016). The documentation I used while writing the answer still referred to the pre-2.10 behavior. I'll try to update this answer soon, but it's really tough to describe because every fifth Git release has to fix another bug in it. :-)