# What's the difference between "* text=auto eol=lf" and "* text eol=lf" in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, gitattributes

This is very similar to this question:
[What is the differrence between `* text=auto` and `* text eol=lf` in .gitattributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590142/what-is-the-differrence-between-text-auto-and-text-eol-lf-in-gitattribu)

But I'm specifically asking why I should use `* text=auto eol=lf` over `* text eol=lf` or vice versa?

From my understanding `eol` overrides the `text` setting, so what's the point in using the former? Is there a difference? If so - how?

I'm reading so many websites and Stack Overflow questions/answers right now - but I'm still utterly confused. Especially when I see this change: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.0.txt#L248

I find the phrasing of the change so hard to read that I'm now none the wiser. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git has code in it to *detect* whether a file is text or binary.

If a file has a lot of zero (ASCII NUL) bytes in it towards the front, that file is deemed binary.  The same goes for some other binary patterns.

Git uses this code, by default, to decide whether to show you a diff, when `git diff` detects some change in some file.  If the file appears to be binary, Git says "binary files differ" (by default—you can make it print a usable diff, and `git format-patch` forces that behavior, for instance).  Otherwise, the file appears to be text so yo uget a regular diff.

Git *also* uses this code for `text=auto` in `.gitattributes`, but *not* for `text`-without-`=auto`.  So:

```
* text=auto eol=<whatever>
```

tells Git: *Every time you extract the file from the index to the work-tree, apply the detection code to the file.  If the detection code claims that the file is a text file, apply the end of line conversions while rehydrating the freeze-dried copy of the file from the index into the usable form in the work-tree.  If the detection code claims that the file is binary, leave it alone.*<sup>1</sup>

By contrast, `* text eol=<whatever>` tells Git: *Every time you rehydrate the file into the work-tree, apply the end of line conversions.*  The bug in Git before version 2.10 was that `* text=auto` accidentally meant `* text` instead of `* text=auto`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since the text-detection sometimes—though not all that often—misfires on (e.g.) `.jpg` image files, it's not wise to *depend* on `text=auto`.  But it works *most* of the time.

Comment: I finally understand why this lengthy explanation was needed as there is so much going on behind the scenes. If you do not read the documentation carefully (like I didn't) then it's very easy to be overwhelmed and left confused. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The question that remains is when you should use one over the other. My current understanding is that it all depends on the pattern. `*` of course is pretty broad so it's more likely that you catch some binary files as well. In that case you might want to have `text=auto` to have some protection against binary files getting normalized. In my particular case there are almost no binary files so I could go with `* text eol=lf` and I can use `*.resource binary` to flag any non-text files as binary (*.resource in my case). But in most cases `* text=auto eol=lf` is the way to go. Do you agree?

Comment: @Semmel: Well... I avoid WIndows, and hence don't need or want my VCS to mess with my files, which means I don't want or need *any* of these. However, when working with repositories that *are* used on Windows systems (e.g., the Git repository for Git), what I observe is that the others call out every file extension and/or path explicitly: they never leave it for Git to guess whether a file is text or binary.

Comment: That is a good point you make there. I have a repository where it's LF all the way - but occasionally a CRLF creeps in. That is the only case where `* text=auto eol=lf` might be viable - in every other setup I would also opt for declaring everything explicitly.