# Does text=auto in .gitattributes always enforce LF line endings and ignore Git's core.autocrlf and core.eol settings?

Tags: git, newline, line-endings, core.autocrlf, lf

This is essentially a follow-up to the question asked here about the difference between `* text=auto` and `* text=auto eol=lf` in a `.gitattributes` config: [What is the difference between "* text=auto" and "* text=auto eol=lf"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633469/what-is-the-difference-between-text-auto-and-text-auto-eol-lf/70636508#70636508)

I think I understand how Git works, but I'd like confirmation because the docs are confusing.

[The docs for the `text` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_text) state:

> This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization. When a text file is normalized, **its line endings are converted to LF** in the repository. To control what line ending style is used in the working directory, **use the eol attribute for a single file and the core.eol configuration variable for all text files**. Note that setting core.autocrlf to true or input overrides core.eol (see the definitions of those options in git-config[1]).

So it sounds like Git enforces `LF` by default if you use `* text=auto`, making `* text=auto eol=lf` redundant.

However, the second bolded part of the quote is what's confusing me: Does Git ever respect `core.autocrlf` or `core.eol`? I tested this on a Windows machine using PowerShell and Git 2.16.1:

1. Run `git config --global core.autocrlf false` and `git config --global core.eol crlf`. The latter is not what you'd usually want, but it's useful for this experiment to see if Git even picks it up at all.
2. Create a text file using Notepad with multiple lines of content. The file should have `CRLF` line endings.
3. Initialize a Git repo in the same directory.
4. Add the file to Git's index.
5. Run `git ls-files --eol` and observe that the file has `CRLF` in both the index and working tree.
6. Add a `.gitattributes` file with `* text = auto`. Commit it.
7. Run `git add --renormalize .` to renormalize the previously committed file.
8. Run `git status`. Observe that the file has been staged for commit.
9. After committing the file, run `git ls-files --eol` to observe that the file now uses `LF` in the index.

So despite me setting `core.eol=crlf` and turning off `core.autocrlf`, Git still enforced `LF` for line endings.

**Question**: Are the docs misleading? Will `text=auto` always enforce `LF`?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out:

- `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol` only impact line endings in **the working tree**, not in Git's **index** (which will always use `LF` when normalization is enabled) or the remote copy of your code. Hence the output of `git ls-files --eol`.
- The `eol` attribute in `.gitattributes` implies `text`, which means it enforces `LF` in the index and whatever value you've set for `eol` in the working directory. Example: `eol=crlf` implies `index = LF` and `working tree = CRLF`.

So the docs are slightly misleading in that `text=auto` does NOT rely on `core.autocrlf` or `core.eol`—it *always* enforces `LF` line endings for the index. Line endings in the working tree are left as-is unless you configure `core.autocrlf`, `core.eol`, or use the `eol` attribute.

Comment: That's not quite right: bk2204 notes that `eol=lf` or `eol=crlf` forces `text` to be fully set (not just set to auto): see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70633469/1256452). This behavior changed between Git 2.9 and 2.10, apparently.

Comment: Hm: According to the release notes, `* text=auto eol=lf` meant `* text eol=lf` in Git 2.9 an earlier, but no longer does in 2.10 and later, so that was considered to be a bug. Since you're on Git 2.16 you won't have this bug, presumably.

Comment: In any case, *if* the file *is* detected as text, the `eol=` setting will indeed always normalize the index copy to have LF-only, as you said. However, *if* Git decides that the file is binary, the index copy won't be tweaked.

Comment: @torek Right, I'm mainly concerned about modern Git versions. The way I understood it, `eol` implies `text`. Whenever `text` is used, line endings in the index become `LF`. If `text=auto` (with or without an `eol` attribute), Git will use its auto-detection algorithm to only apply this normalization to text files. Then, `eol`'s primary function is to change the line endings in the working directory.

Comment: `=auto` does not _rely_ on `core.autocrlf` or `core.eol`, it _defers_ to them. `core.eol` is only used on checkout, and only if `core.autocrlf=false` or unset.